# Menu buttons change shadows on click React/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, menuitem

I am trying to achieve this by using CSS, i am using "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu", and as i am styling the menuitems, .menu-item:hover & .`menu-item:active`  works well but .menu-item:visitedisnt, i tried several ways but i cant seem to control the menuitem after clicking it, here is a snippet of the code, its set on current moduleview

https://codesandbox.io/s/qk1v5n0z5w?fontsize=14&moduleview=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the `box-shadow` of buttons change whenever users click:

```
.menu-item:active {
  background: #fafafa;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  border: 9px solid #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px #cc0f0fa6;
  color: #cc0f0f4d;
}
```

but there is no CSS for .menu-item:visited. The reason is your buttons are not links(they are `<div>`) Browsers limits the styles that can be set for `a:visited` links, due to security issues.

Allowed styles are:

- color
- background-color
- border-color (and border-color for separate sides)
- outline color
- column-rule-color
- the color parts of fill and stroke

All other styles are inherited from a:link.

Comment: Isn't there any way around it?